# Error handling approach for parameter errors in Typescript modules?

Tags: object-oriented, typescript

I have been tormented by the question of how to handle parameter errors by consumers of my modules, and also in classes which are extended from base classes. The particular sort of concern I have is around map keys in various utility classes.  What if the consumer provides a key that doesn't exist in the collection, or attempts to add a new member with a key that already exists.

For example, lets say I have a collection class called 'SortedMap' which enables a user to enter an item in a particular position in the collection and then enables the user to retrieve the item by its position in the collection or by its key, and also enables the user to change the position of an item in the collection by modifying its sort property:

```
interface MapPosition {
    sort: number;
    index: number;
}

export interface MapItem {
    id: string;
    index: number;
    sort: number;
}

export class SortedMap<T extends MapItem> {
    private _list: Array<T>;
    private _map: Map<string, T>;
    private _sorting: boolean; //status variable to prevent recursive 
                               //calls in sortChangehandler.
    private _positionMap: Map<string, MapPosition>;

    constructor() {
        this._sorting = false;
        this._list = Array<T>();
        this._map = new Map<string, T>();
        this._positionMap = new Map<string, MapPosition>();
    }

    get positionMap() {
        return this._positionMap;
    }

    private addSortChangeHandler(item: T): T {
        let self = this;
        if (this._positionMap.has(item.id)) {
            throw "This item is already in the collection!"
        }
        let myPosition = <MapPosition>{};
        myPosition.index = 0;
        myPosition.sort = 0;
        self._positionMap.set(item.id, myPosition);
        let watcher = <ProxyHandler<T>>{}

        watcher.set = function (target, p, value, receiver) {
            let myPosition: MapPosition;
            let resortRequired = false;
            myPosition = self._positionMap.get(receiver.id)!;
            switch (p) {
                case "sort":
                    if (value < 0) { value = -1 }
                    myPosition.sort = value;
                    if (!self._sorting) {
                        resortRequired = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "index":
                    myPosition.index = <number>value;
                    break;
                case "id":
                    target.id = <string>value;
                    break;
            }
            if (resortRequired) {
                resortRequired = false;
                console.log("resort triggered by sort change");
                self.sortIndex();
            }
            return true;
        }

        watcher.get = function (target: T, prop: string, receiver) {
            let myId = item["id"];
            let myPosition = self._positionMap.get(myId)!;
            switch (prop) {
                case 'index':
                    return myPosition.index;
                case 'sort':
                    return myPosition.sort;
                case 'id':
                    return myId;
                default:
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            }
        }
        let proxy = new Proxy(item, watcher);
        return proxy;
    }

    getItem(id: string): T {
        if (!this._map.has(id)) {
            throw `The id ${id} was not found in this Map`;
        } else {
            let value = this._map.get(id);
            return this._map.get(id)!;
        }
    };

    getAt(index: number): T {
        if (!(this.existsIndex(index))) {
            throw `error [SortedMap.getAt()] An invalid index (${index}) was supplied to getAt.  The map has ${this.count} items.`;
        }
        return this._list[index];
    }

    get list(): Array<T> {
        return this._list;
    }

    first(): T | null {
        if (this.count > 0) {
            return this.getAt(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    last(): T | null {
        let mycount = this.count;
        if (mycount === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return this._list[mycount - 1];
    }

    add(item: T, key?: string): T {
        if (key === undefined || key === "")
            if (!item.id) {
                throw "Can't add item with neither key or undefined id.";
            } else {
                {
                    key = item.id
                };
            }
        if (this.exists(key)) {
            throw "attempt to add duplicate key " + key;
        }
        let proxyItem = this.addSortChangeHandler(item);
        this._list.push(proxyItem);
        this._map.set(key, proxyItem);

        this.makeIndex();
        return proxyItem
    }

    remove(key: string): T | null {

        if (this._map.has(key)) {
            let item = this._map.get(key)!;
            this._map.delete(key);
            this._list = Array.from(this._map.values());
            this.sortIndex();
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    exists(key: string): boolean {
        if (!key) {
            throw "Can't call exists on falsey key.";
        }
        return this._map.has(key);
    }

    existsIndex(index: number): boolean {
        if ((index < 0) || (index > (this._list.length - 1))) { return false }
        return true;
    }

    moveUp(id: string): void {
        let f = this.getItem(id);
        if (f.index === 0) {
            return;
        }
        f.sort = ((f.index - 1) * 10) - 1
    }

    moveDown(id: string): void {
        let f = this.getItem(id);
        if (f.index >= this.count - 1) { return; }
        f.sort = ((f.index + 1) * 10) + 1;
    }




    insertBeforeIndex(index: number, item: T): T {
        if (this.exists(item.id)) { throw `duplicate key - ${item.id}` }
        if (!this.existsIndex(index)) throw `index out of range - ${index}`;

        this._sorting = true;
        let olditem = this._list[index];

        item.sort = olditem.sort - 1;
        this._list.push(item);
        this._map.set(item.id, item);
        this._sorting = false;
        this.sortIndex();

        return item;
    }


    insertBeforeKey(beforeKey: string, item: T) {
        if (this.exists(item.id)) { throw `duplicate key - ${item.id}` }
        if (this.exists(beforeKey)) {

            let insertAt = this.getItem(beforeKey)!.sort - 1;
            this._sorting = true;
            item.sort = insertAt;
            this._list.push(item);
            this._sorting = false;
            this.sortIndex();
            return item;
        } else {
            throw `beforeKey ${beforeKey} not found`;
        }
    }

    /**sets the sort index property and the index property based on teh current
     * position of each item in the list.
     */
    private makeIndex(): void {
        let counter: number = 0;
        this._sorting = true;
        this._list.forEach(function (item) {
            item.index = counter;

            item.sort = (counter * 10);

            counter += 1;
        });
        this._sorting = false;

    }
    /**sorts the list by the current sort index, sets the index and 
     * sort property of each item based on its new position in the list.
     * 
    **/
    sortIndex(): void {
        this._sorting = true
        this._list.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.sort > b.sort ? 1 : -1;
        });
        this.makeIndex();
        this._sorting = false;

    }

    get count(): number {
        return this._list.length;
    }

}
```

At one point, I decided that I should gracefully handle all errors where an "incorrect" parameter was supplied, for example, by returning "undefined" or "null" where a `getItem(key: string)` was supplied a non-existent key.   However I discovered  the approach of gracefully handling things so exceptions weren't thrown covered up bugs so that it was much harder to figure out why I had an error internal to the class.  So I started throwing exceptions for errors like these, but I have a nagging concern that this approach makes it more likely that end user experience will be more seriously impaired when errors occur due to unforeseen edge cases, where the running program just stops altogether and returns an error message that's meaningless to anybody but a developer.

So for example, lets say somebody consumes a SortedMap as follows:

```
import {SortedMap} from "../lib/util";
import {MapItem} from "../lib/util";

class Account implements MapItem {
    id: string;    
    index: number = 0;
    sort: number = 0;
    name: string
    balance: number;

    constructor(id : string, name: string, balance: number)   {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
 }

class Accounts extends SortedMap<Account> {
    getAccountById(id: string) : Account {
        return this.getItem(id);
    }
    getTotal() {
        let total=0;
        for (let ac of this.list) {
            total += ac.balance;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the sensible way to handle an issue where the consumer of `Accounts` called `getAccountById` with an id that hadn't been added to the collection?

Assuming that this class is consumed by say a Angular application, would it make the most sense to

a) do nothing, and let the method call return the error thrown by SortedMap, ("The id {...} was not found in this Map.")
 b) check for existence of the key in Accounts.getAccountById using SortedMap.exists(id), and throw an error like "This account does not exist"
 c) return undefined or null or some object which represents a non-existent account

Or something else entirely.  I guess the question is about balancing ease of debugging, how much time it takes to write parameter error traps all along the call chain, and the effect on end user encountering undiscovered errors that show up in production code.

I'm never quite sure how to balance these various competing priorities with a coherent error handling approach.

Advice welcome.